# How to pass use lstlisting or lstinline in a command

Tags: listings

I'm trying to define a command that typesets Maxima code by taking three arguments - the command number, the input text, and the output math.  I want the input text - the second argument - formatted as a listing.  This is the closest I've gotten:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\maximaio}[3]{
\begin{tabular}{l l}
(\%i#1) &
\lstinline!#2! \\
(\%o#1) &
$ #3 $
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\maximaio{1}{y
/
(y+1);}{{y}\over{y+1}}

\end{document}
```

If you run this, you'll see that the newlines aren't correctly formatted in the second argument.  Instead of "y", "/", and "(y+1);" on three separate lines, I get "y / (y+1);" on a single line.

Can anybody suggest how to pass a listing into a command like this?

Comment: Beside the problems with verbatim as argument: `\lstinline` doesn't print (or like) newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily pass verbatim content as part of macro arguments. So, I suggest an alternative option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand{\maximaio}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    (\%i#1) &
    \BUseVerbatim{MaximaCode} \\
    (\%o#1) &
    $ #2 $
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{MaximaCode}
y
/
(y+1);
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\maximaio{1}{\frac{y}{y+1}}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, `SaveVerbatim` is used to store the code inside a box called `MaximaCode`. With a call to `\maximaio{<cmd>}{<output>}`, the code is processed and placed inside a `tabular`.