# link of web.archive.org that redirects to link with % characters

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, hyperref, urls, url

I am trying to use a code compile-able by both by biblatex (biber) and bibtex but it contains this link in the bibliography:

```
https://web.archive.org/web/20110412120322/http://www.allheadlinenews.com/briefs/articles/90043651?After%20hesitation%2C%20Jordan%20joins%20in%20Libya%20no-fly%20campaign
```

The problem is that web.archive redirects to something that backslashed `%` characters are becoming `/%` instead of just `%`.

MWE:

main.tex :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\xdef\UseBibLaTeX{1}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}


\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=authoryear,
natbib=true,
]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{References.bib}
\else
  \usepackage{natbib}
  \renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}
\fi
  
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{cite01}

\begin{sloppypar}
\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
  \printbibliography
\else
  \bibliographystyle{agsm}
  \bibliography{References}
\fi
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

References.bib:

```
@article{cite01,
        title ={After hesitation, {Jordan} joins in {Libya} no-fly campaign},
        url ={https://web.archive.org/web/20110412120322/http://www.allheadlinenews.com/briefs/articles/90043651?After\%20hesitation\%2C\%20Jordan\%20joins\%20in\%20Libya\%20no-fly\%20campaign},
        urldate ={2020-08-04},
        month =Apr,
        author={{TML Staff}},
        journal={{All Headline News (AHN)}},
        year ={2011},
        day={06}
}
```

Comment: why are you escaping the % in the bib-file?

Comment: I had some issues without escaping when using bibtex (let me check and reproduce)

Comment: With `biblatex` you should definitely not escape any US-ASCII chars (that includes `%`) in URLs. Most BibTeX styles that properly support URL will also have no problem with unescaped `%`s (at least when `url` or `hyperref` is loaded). If there is a BibTeX style that has a `url` field yet does not support `%`, then I would call that a deficiency of that style.

Comment: I see the problem. Define `\harvardurl` as `\renewcommand\harvardurl{\textbf{URL:} \url}` and not as *`\renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}`

Comment: as moewe writes your harvardurl command is wrong.

Comment: @moewe ... I got that command from you some ages before ... Please correct the thread ...  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455700/120578

Comment: It was throuing the error `Runaway argument?
{https://web.archive.org/web/20110412120322/http://www.allheadlinenew\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \harvardurl.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3259   \bibliography{References}`

Comment: Well, you live and learn. Corrected.

Comment: You may add an answer too here with your solution @moewe ... May be will be helpful for future visitors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `biblatex` you should not (LaTeX-)escape any US-ASCII chars in the `url` field. That means that `%` should remain `%` and should not be escaped as `\%`.

With BibTeX the situation is not as uniform. The original standard BibTeX styles date back to the eighties before URLs were standardised and therefore don't have a dedicated `url` field. Later BibTeX styles have URL support, but the exact implementation varies. *Most* BibTeX styles interface with the `url` or `hyperref` package and thus support unescaped URL input. This may, however, not be the case for all styles. But I wouldn't use that as an excuse to insist on escaping `%`s in URLs, instead I would say that this is a deficiency of those styles.

In this case the solution is simple. Instead of

```
\renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}
```

use

```
\renewcommand\harvardurl{\textbf{URL:} \url}
```

The way TeX reads arguments makes `\url`'s tricks to handle special characters break down when it is used in the argument of another command. (This is the same phenomenon you can observe with macros like `\verb` or `\lstinline`. See for example http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin, [How to pass use lstlisting or lstinline in a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355083/35864), [How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24574/35864.)) In the new definition we cunningly avoid explicitly giving `\url`'s argument and thus allow `\url`'s magic to continue to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\xdef\UseBibLaTeX{0}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}


\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=authoryear,
natbib=true,
]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\else
  \usepackage{natbib}
  \renewcommand\harvardurl{\textbf{URL:} \url}
\fi
  
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cite01,
  title   = {After hesitation, {Jordan} joins in {Libya} no-fly campaign},
  url     = {https://web.archive.org/web/20110412120322/http://www.allheadlinenews.com/briefs/articles/90043651?After%20hesitation\%2C%20Jordan%20joins%20in%20Libya%20no-fly%20campaign},
  urldate = {2020-08-04},
  month   = Apr,
  author  = {{TML Staff}},
  journal = {All Headline News (AHN)},
  year    = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{cite01}

\begin{sloppypar}
\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
  \printbibliography
\else
  \bibliographystyle{agsm}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\fi
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image: Correctly displayed URL 'https://web.archive.org/web/20110412120322/http://www.allheadlinenews.com/briefs/articles/90043651?After%20hesitation2C%20Jordan%20joins%20in%20Libya%20no-fly%20campaign']

Comment: Thanks @moewe ... Works perfectly ... Useful info too.